# Moving Standard Deviation in Python WITHOUT using built-in functions

Tags: python, moving-average, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the moving standard deviation array of my dataset. I have my original position and time data and have also found the moving average array of this position data. I have have seen the various built in python functions for calculating rolling mean and standard deviations. I am hesitant to use this because a parameter I must set is the direction of the process window (forward: current time to window length, centered: window length centered about current time, backward: window length to current time). This affects the range of data that I must use at each data point. Below is my code for calculating moving average error.

```
def MA(pos, t, processWindow, positionTolerance, calculationDirection, figNum):
    #pos and t are position and time lists, processWindow is given in seconds, but represent 
     the length of the window 

    N = len(t)
    windowLength = processWindow*1000 #process window given in seconds---> length becomes 50
    

    i = 0
    MA = []
    while i < N:
        if calculationDirection == 'Forward':
           startPos = i
           endPos = int(i+ windowLength)

        elif calculationDirection == 'Centered':
           startPos = int(i-windowLength/2)
           endPos = int(i+windowLength/2)

        elif calculationDirection == 'Backward':
            startPos = int(i-windowLength)
            endPos = i
            
        window = pos[startPos : endPos]
        window_average = round(sum(window) / windowLength, 4)
        MA.append(window_average)
        
        i+=1
    return MA
```

`MA` returns a list with the moving average value at each position point. Is there a way to compute the moving standard deviation in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to compute the moving standard deviation in a similar manner?

Simply change the formula in `window_average = ...`:

```
import math

def std(data: list) -> float:
    N = len(data)
    mean = sum(data) / N
    variance = sum((x - mean)**2 for x in data) / (N - 1)
    return math.sqrt(variance)

def moving_std(pos, t, processWindow, positionTolerance, calculationDirection, figNum):
    # Same thing as in your `MA` function...
    ...
    while ...:
        window = pos[startPos : endPos]
        window_std = std(window) # new formula
        MA.append(window_std)
        # go on with the loop...

    return MA
```